# Angular 2 two way binding using ngModel is not working

Tags: data-binding, typescript, angular, 2-way-object-databinding

Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a know property of the 'input' element and there are no matching directives with a corresponding property

Note: im using alpha.31

```
import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
    selector: 'data-bind'
})
@View({
    template:`
        <input id="name" type="text" 
            [ng-model]="name" 
            (ng-model)="name = $event" />
        {{ name }}
    ` 
})
class DataBinding { 
    name: string;

    constructor(){
        this.name = 'Jose';
    }
}

bootstrap(DataBinding);
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Angular has released its final version on 15th of September. Unlike Angular 1 you can use `ngModel` directive in Angular 2 for two way data binding, but you need write it in a bit different way like `[(ngModel)]` (**Banana in a box syntax**). Almost all angular2 core directives doesn't support `kebab-case` now instead you should use `camelCase`.

> Now `ngModel` directive belongs to `FormsModule`, that's why you should `import` the `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms` module inside `imports` metadata option of `AppModule`(NgModule). Thereafter you can use `ngModel` directive inside  on your page.

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel"/>
    {{myModel}}
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  myModel: any;
}
```

**app/app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ], //< added FormsModule here
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app/main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ya2GS32WImbAQBLmH0Sv?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for `Banana in a box syntax` - now I'll never forget which one goes on the outside!

Answer (score 57):

**Key Points:**

1. ngModel in angular2 is valid only if the FormsModule is available as a part of your AppModule.
2. `ng-model` is syntatically wrong.
3. square braces [..] refers to the property binding.
4. circle braces (..) refers to the event binding.
5. when square and circle braces are put together as [(..)]  refers two way binding, commonly called banana box.

So, to fix your error.

**Step 1:** Importing FormsModule

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
```

**Step 2:** Add it to imports array of your AppModule as

```
imports :[ ... , FormsModule ]
```

**Step 3:** Change `ng-model` as ngModel with banana boxes as

```
 <input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
```

**Note:** Also, you can handle the two way databinding separately as well as below

```
<input id="name" type="text" [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="valueChange($event)"/>

valueChange(value){

}
```

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I was missing a "name" attribute on my input element.

Comment: Good lord!! Thanks.

Comment: This was my problem too

Answer (score 9):

As per Angular2 final, you do not even have to import `FORM_DIRECTIVES` as suggested above by many. However, the syntax has been changed as [kebab-case was dropped](http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2016/02/angular-2-templates-will-it-parse.html) for the betterment.

Just replace `ng-model` with `ngModel` and wrap it in [a box of bananas](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3008-two-way-data-binding-is-just-a-box-of-bananas-in-angular-2-beta-1.htm). But you have spilt the code into two files now:

**app.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template: `
    <input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"  />
    {{ name }}
  `
})
export class DataBindingComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Jose';
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { DataBindingComponent } from './app'; //app.ts above

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DataBindingComponent],
  imports:      [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  bootstrap:    [DataBindingComponent]
})
export default class MyAppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule);
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer that helped me:
[The directive [(ngModel)]= not working anymore in rc5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886276/the-directive-ngmodel-not-working-anymore-in-rc5)

To sum it up: input fields now require property `name` in the form.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. I put the name attribute in input and worked

Comment: what the actual heck? why does it even need that attribute? this was the most unexpected solution for me.

Answer (score 8):

**Note** : To allow the ngModel exists Independently inside reactive form, we have to use **ngModelOptions** as follows:

```
 [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
```

**For Example :**

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
            <input
              matInput 
              [(ngModel)]="accountType"
              [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
            />
 </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Later in the @NgModule decorator's import:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule
]

})
```

Answer (score 3):

**Angular 2 Beta**

This answer is for those who use **Javascript** for angularJS v.2.0 Beta.

To use `ngModel` in your view you should tell the angular's compiler that you are using a directive called `ngModel`.

**How?**

To use `ngModel` there are two libraries in angular2 Beta, and they are `ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES` and `ng.common.NgModel`.

Actually `ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES` is nothing but group of directives which are useful when you are creating a form. It includes `NgModel` directive also.

```
app.myApp = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'App/Pages/myApp.html',
    directives: [ng.common.NgModel] // specify all your directives here
}).Class({
    constructor: function () {
        this.myVar = {};
        this.myVar.text = "Testing";
    },

});
```

Comment: FYI NgModel is in FORM_DIRECTIVES, so you could also:
    directives: [ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES]

Comment: @PeterJ.Hart, Actually `ng.common.NgModel` contains the defenition for the directive `ngModel`. `ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES` is grouping some directive's including `ngModel` which are useful if forms. So we don't want to include each and every directive's for the form just include `ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES`

Answer (score 2):

These things are missing/ Wrong:

- Import **FormsModule** in imports array of module (ngModel requires FormsModule)
- ngModel is written as: **`[(ngModel)]="modelName"`**

This way, It will work fine!

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Angular:

1. -write it as `[(ngModel)] = yourSearch`
2. declare a empty variable(property) named as `yourSearch` in `.ts` file
3. add `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts` file from - `@angular/forms;`
4. if your application is running, then restart it as you made changes in its `module.ts` file

Answer (score 1):

if you are using lazy loading module, you need to import ngModule and formModule in the current module.
example:

```
//shared.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

imports: [
    FormsModule,]
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of ng-model you can use this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input #box (keyup)="0">
    <p>{{box.value}}</p>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

inside your app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to following files.

**app.component.ts**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fname" >
{{fname}}
export class appcomponent {
fname:any;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

import FormsModule in your AppModule to work with two way binding [(ngModel)] with your

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a name property solved the problem for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).