# How to show and hide a div with a checkbox element in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I've got a checkbox and what I'm trying to achieve is to hide the `div` when the checkbox is checked and show when it is unchecked in Angular 2.0 beta.

I know how to do this in angular 1.2 with this code

```
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showhidepregnant"/> Pregnant
</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Code on the `div`

```
<div class="col-md-4 divhidetxtdpatient" ng-hide="showhidemasked">
      <input class="form-control" tabindex="1" id="id_field_specialist" ng-model="id_field_specialist" type="text" ng-blur="savespecialist()" placeholder="maskable"/>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even try to find a solution in your own ? Have you a plunkr with your actual solution ?

Answer (score 11):

Provide `[(ngModel)]` for your checkbox and use the same `ngModel` using `*ngIf` for your div tag. See the below code sample.

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showhidepregnant"/> Pregnant
</label>
```

Then use the same mode:

```
<div class="col-md-4 divhidetxtdpatient" *ngIf="showhidepregnant">
```

NB: Please declare the model in your **.ts** file also:

```
showhidepregnant: boolean;
```

Comment: Can we use same format for the reactive forms on the angular

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the **#variable** syntax from Angular. **checked** (**register.checked**) is the property of the input element which returns the checked state of the element.


**Note**: the event-binding **(checked)** is needed to trigger the check for changes if the user has checked/unchecked the checkbox:

```html
<div *ngIf="register.checked">
  <h1>Hallo</h1>
</div>
<label><input (change)="register" #register type="checkbox"> Register</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to use `[hidden]` property binding for showing and hiding HTML.

And then use `[(ngModel)]` for [**two way binding in Angular2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624864/2435473) & use `(eventName)` to have event bounded to DOM.

**Markup**

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showhidepregnant"/> Pregnant
</label>

<div class="col-md-4 divhidetxtdpatient" [hidden]="showhidemasked">
   <input class="form-control" tabindex="1" id="id_field_specialist" 
   [(ngModel)]="id_field_specialist" type="text" 
   (blur)="savespecialist()" placeholder="maskable"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check whether checkbox is checked or not by applying `(change)` hook on the basis of checkbox property try to hide or show div,

here is working plnkr for same:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/mIj619FncOpfdwrR0KeG?p=preview

.ts file code:

```
checked(value){
    if(document.getElementById('abc').checked==true){
      this.shown= true
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('abc').checked==false)
      this.shown= false;
  }
```

.html

```
<input type='checkbox' id= 'abc' (change)="checked('abc')">

<div *ngIf='shown'>
  Hello CheckBox
</div>
```