# The directive [(ngModel)]= not working anymore in rc5

Tags: angular

ngModel is throwing exceptions, this worked fine in rc4

```
<input [(ngModel)]="par.name" placeholder="name" />
```

These are the exceptions:

> zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:260 Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in
>   ./CommunityListComponent class CommunityListComponent - inline
>   template:10:27 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for form control
>   with unspecified name ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: Error: No value accessor
>   for form control with unspecified name

Comment: You can resolve it by adding formControlName like this ```<input [(ngModel)]="par.name" placeholder="name" formControlName="name"/>```

Answer (score 19):

can also solve by importing FormsModule into your bootstrap module, then it will be available to all components.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from 'app/components/app';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It is also mentioned on the tutorial itself - [https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#import-the-formsmodule](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#import-the-formsmodule)

Answer (score 8):

Now you need to set the name on input. For example;

```
<input [(ngModel)]="par.name" **name="name"** placeholder="name" />
```

And all directive must be set on *.module.ts.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>

      <input [(ngModel)]="employee.empName">

      `,
      directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    export class AppComponent { 
      employee = { empName: 'Sanket', email: '', phone: '', address:'' };

       ngOnInit() { 
       }
    }
```

This is working for me in RC5.

Reference - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgModel-directive.html

Comment: thanks - it worked for me as well - although i'm using rc.5 FromModule and ngModel definition as indicated in the docs - i'm not sure why it happens. FORM_DIRECTIVES should be deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Two things you need to do while using two-way binding syntax in forms in RC5.

1. Include FormsModule in your app.module.ts
2. Use name attribute in your html input tags like this:

   `<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="par.name" />`

That's all.

Comment: Thankyou. This helped me. I watched 4 tutorials and now one of them mentioned having to put in the name tag

Comment: I have been banging my head since 4 hours, thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2):

At the app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Then at `@NgModule(){imports:[FormsModule]}` with other staff

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it explicitly that changes are being made. Please observe:

1. import `{ChangeDetectorRef}`
2. declare its object in constructor.
3. `this.object.detectChanges();` in function where changes are being made

Comment: it will work although it's an overkill

Answer (score 0):

There's another simple substitute as follows:

```js
item: string = "";
```

```html
<input name= "item" (input)= "item=$event.target.value">
<h1>{{item}}<h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it by adding formControlName like this  `<input [(ngModel)]="par.name" placeholder="name" formControlName="name"/>`

Here I attach an image when I use `[(ngModel)]` in `<input/>` without `formControlName`

[image]

I hope It helps you...