# Angular2 unable to import FormsModule with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing the Angular2 Heroes Tutorial:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html
 in plain Javascript (not Typescript) and i am having trouble to Import the Forms Module as mentioned: (description is only for Typescript):

> Before we can use two-way data binding for form inputs, we need to import the FormsModule package in our Angular module. We add it to the NgModule decorator's imports array. This array contains the list of external modules used by our application.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When i am adding the Forms module to my app.module.js import array, it fails to find the module:

> zone.js:129 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'class2'

Here is my app.module.js:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppModule =
    ng.core.NgModule({
      imports: [ ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES],
      declarations: [ app.AppComponent],
      bootstrap: [ app.AppComponent ]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

in my node_modules folder the Forms module exists. If i remove "ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES" from the imports array, no error is thrown.

The Content of console.dir(ng) is:

```
Object
    common:Object
    compiler:Object
    core:Object
    coreTokens:Object
    platformBrowser:Object
    platformBrowserDynamic:Object
    probe
    :
    inspectNativeElement(element /** TODO #9100 */)
    __proto__:Object
```

The content of console.dir(ng.forms) is:

```
undefined
```

Comment: Can you post the content of: console.dir(ng); and console.dir(ng.forms); ?

Comment: @IvRRimUm : i posted the content above.

Comment: What are you using for a server? The code looks right.

Comment: i am using MAMP Version 3.5 (3.5). Strange Thing is that the "platform-browser" node_module is loading correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry, i found the error. As so often it was nothing having to do with typescript or angular, i just had to add the script tag in the index.html file to load the forms.umd.js:

```
<script src="../node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js"></script>
```

now i can import the Forms Module with the following code and i can use the ngModule functionality:

```
ng.core.NgModule({
  imports: [ ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.forms.FormsModule],
  declarations: [ app.AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [ app.AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: I had the same error. But by including forms.umd.js, I get the error: Cannot read property '__core_private__' of undefined(…)

Comment: Ah... I found my error: I had to load the forms.umd.js script AFTER loading the main module scripts in the index.html file.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';`

Source: [Angular 2 two way binding using ngModel is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623879/angular-2-two-way-binding-using-ng-model-is-not-working)

EDIT:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FORM_DIRECTIVES
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If this doesn't work, post the console.dir(ng); again( with this code in use ).

Comment: could you translate that in plain javascript? i tried adding "ng.common. FORM_DIRECTIVES" to the import array, but that didn´t work.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: this code is still in typescript right? i am using plain javascript.

Comment: Import is the same in typescript as in javascript.

Comment: i updated my javascript file app.module.js in my question and changed from "ng.forms.FormsModule" to "ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES". I cannot use your code from the answer because it is typescript.