# how update model value when input value is changed in Angularjs2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I want to change model value from input tag but I don't know how to do it in best way.

here is my code that I have done for that.

```
<div *ngFor='let l of list'>
    <input #temp [value]='l.test' (blur)='l.test=temp.value'/>
    <span (click)='check(l,temp.value)'></span>
<div>
```

angular code

```
check(l,temp:string)
{
   console.log(l.test);
   console.log(temp);
}
```

I want to do this without a blur event.
please suggest me any better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can `[(ngModel)]` on the field, that would provide you two way binding on field, as soon as you type in something it would change the `l.test` value of particular element from an array.

**Markup**

```
<div *ngFor='let l of list'>
    <input [(ngModel)]='l.test'/>
<div>
```

---

Since `Angular 2 rc-5`, to make `ngModel` two way binding working you have import `FormsModule` in your `@NgModule`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
///..other imports

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ], //< added FormsModule here
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

You could refer [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624864/2435473) to know how to use two way binding in Angular 2.

[**Plunkr here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BvJxcvAEVPOht3r3WIqR?p=preview)

Comment: Error:-Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya you have to import `FormsModule` in your `NgModule` to use two way binding feature using `ngModel` directive. checkout updated answer, & linked answer both would help you..

Comment: @PravinTukadiya does it helped you?

Comment: Thanks,@Pankaj Parkar