# md-input binding error in Angular2 stable version

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I've got a common error while upgrading an `angular2` app to stable version but none of the mentioned solutions worked for me (which is almost a widespread only one solution).
Here is it :

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'md-input'.
1. If 'md-input' is an Angular component and it has 'placeholder' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I've tried to import the `FormsModule` according to this [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input/) and this [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623879/angular-2-two-way-binding-using-ng-model-is-not-working) (which are the same) but the same error still occuring. Is there an other solution for it ?

the HTML :

```
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
      <div class="md-block">
        <md-input
          id="name"
          [ngModel]="xyzStuff?.xyz_name"
          placeholder="{{'xyzName' | translate}}"
          formControlName="name"
          dividerColor="{{getDividerColor(xyzForm.controls.name)}}"
        >
        </md-input>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the `Module file` :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { UIRouterModule } from 'ui-router-ng2';
import { TranslateModule } from 'ng2-translate';

import { ParComponent } from './par.component';
import { XyzSettingsComponent } from './shared/xyz-settings/xyz-settings.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ParComponent,
    XyzSettingsComponent
  ],
  imports:       [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule,
    TranslateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers:     [],
  exports:       [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule,
    TranslateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class ParModule {}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`md-input` is belongs to `angular2` material project. Angular 2 Material is entirely different plugin. You have to make sure you import `MaterialModule` imported and injected inside `imports` option of `NgModule`.

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports:       [
    ...,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(), //<-- imported material module here
    ...
  ],
  providers:     [],
  exports:       [
    ...
  ]
})
```

I'd highly recommend you to go through the [**Getting started page Angular2 material**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

> **Note:**
>   Make sure you should import `MaterialModule` in whichever modules component you want to use `Angular 2 material` components.

Comment: but i already have this in the `app.module` `import { MdInputModule }             from '@angular2-material/input'; and it works in other pages :/
`

Comment: @53l3m the component for which you are getting this error, does it belongs to `ParModule `?

Comment: @53l3m that's the reason, you haven't imported `MaterialModule` form `ParModule`