# Angular 2 data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, components

I am new to angular 2. I am trying to update a variable in my component from an input in my view. Not sure how to bind my input to the variable? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623879/angular-2-two-way-binding-using-ng-model-is-not-working

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use ngModel

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourVariable" />
```

Then in your component, you can make a the variable "yourVariable"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cool-app',
  templateUrl: './something.html',
  styleUrls: ['./something.css']
})
export class TimeSliderComponent {
  private yourVariable: string;

  constructor() { }  
}
```

For more info, check out:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html