# Can't get input field to show on Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following this Angular 4 tutorial:

https://youtu.be/z6qFqlwUxkQ?t=16m33s

And in that part of the video he has the following code:

View:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

Controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
}
```

It works for him but not for me, I'm not getting any compilation errors but the page is blank, I don't see an input field at all. Any idea why? I have the exact same code and am using Angular 4 also..

### EDIT:

here's the contents of **app.modue.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: are you using angular cli?

Comment: @brk yes I 'm using angular cli

Comment: you don't have any errors in the console ?

If not this is probably a routing issue

Comment: I guess you missed to import `FormsModule` where `ngModel` directive resides, check [Angular 2 two way binding using ngModel is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624864/2435473)

Comment: Likely what @PankajParkar mentioned. Check browser console for errors when there aren't compilation errors.

Comment: @Z.Bagley Yes I do see a error in the console, it's `compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@0:19`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post code for **app-module.ts** 
I suspect you are missing something inside @ngModule
Compare that to the video... 
I suspect it's one of **FormsModule** or **ReactiveFormsModule**
haven't watched video... You'll probably be using FormsModule if it's a Hello World type scenario.

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

NgModule({
....
imports: [      ..., 
   FormsModule,  
    ReactiveFormsModule]
....
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Hi, please check my edit. I very well could be missing something, I haven't touched that file yet.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to provide the some code snippets/import hints.

Comment: Yep working now, thanks! I guess the tutorial guy missed showing u need to update this whole part.