# angular2 materialize checkbox not responding

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I can't get my checkboxes to work, they appear and I can click on the box but they don't get checked and my onSelect function isn't getting called either. I'm new to angular so this is probably something simple that I have missed.

Heres my html:

```
<div *ngIf="pager.index < quiz?.questions.length">
  <h5 class="flow-text"><span [innerHTML]="quiz?.questions[pager.index].text"></span></h5>
  <br>
  <div class="row text-left">
    <div class="col s12 m12" *ngFor="let answer of quiz?.questions[pager.index].answers">
      <div class="answer">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="answer.selected" (change)="onSelect(answer);"/><label class="black-text flow-text"> {{answer.text}} </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="row">
    <div class="col s6 m6"></div>
    <div class="col s6 m6">
      <div *ngIf="pager.index < quiz?.questions.length - 1">
        <button id="nextButton" class="btn-flat black-text right flow-text" (click)="goTo(pager.index + 1);">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="pager.index == quiz?.questions.length - 1">
        <button id="nextButton" class="btn-flat black-text right flow-text" (click)="goTo(pager.index + 1);">Finish</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>

<div *ngIf="pager.index == quiz?.questions.length">
  {{ selections }}
</div>
```

here is the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { QuizService } from '../services/quiz.service';
import { Answer, Question, Quiz } from '../models/index';
import {MaterializeAction} from "angular2-materialize";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz',
  templateUrl: './quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz.component.sass'],
  providers: [QuizService]
})
export class QuizComponent implements OnInit {

  quiz: Quiz;
  pager = {
    index: 0,
    size: 1,
    count: 1
  };
  selections: [string]

  constructor(private quizService: QuizService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadQuiz()
  }

  loadQuiz() {

    this.quizService.get().subscribe(res => {
      this.quiz = new Quiz(res);
      this.pager.count = this.quiz.questions.length;
    });
  }

  goTo(index: number) {
   if (index >= 0 ) {
     this.pager.index = index;
   }
 }

 onSelect(answer: Answer) {
   if (answer.selected = true) {
     this.selections.splice(this.selections.indexOf(answer.text), 1);
   } else {
     this.selections.push(answer.text);
   }
   answer.selected = !answer.selected
 }
}
```

Any help would be great as ive tried everything ive seen but to no prevail. Thanks

Update: added app.nodule.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';

import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
import {AuthService} from "./services/auth.service";
import {AuthGuard} from "./guards/auth.guard";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar/toolbar.component';
import { AuthDialogComponent } from './auth-dialog/auth-dialog.component';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './login-form/login-form.component';
import { RegisterFormComponent } from './register-form/register-form.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { QuizComponent } from './quiz/quiz.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    AuthDialogComponent,
    LoginFormComponent,
    RegisterFormComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    QuizComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterializeModule
    ],
  providers: [Angular2TokenService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this issue: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1376 The asker had noticed this:

> I've noticed that checkboxes only appear if they are coded like this:
>     `<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid"><label for="checkboxid">Yes?</label>`

Tried your code, so the following seems to work just fine. We need to add an `id` for your checkboxes, and then also use `for` in the label. Since you are iterating the checkboxes, we need to set dynamic `id` to separate the checkboxes. I used the index for this.

```html
<div class="col s12 m12" 
     *ngFor="let answer of quiz?.questions[pager.index].answers; let i = index">
  <div class="answer">
    <input type="checkbox" [id]="i" [ngModel]="answer.selected" 
      (ngModelChange)="onSelect(answer)"/>
    <label [for]="i" class="black-text flow-text"> {{answer.text}} </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[ngModel]` binding combined with `(ngModelChange)` so that whenever your checkbox value changes, the `ngModelChange` will call the `onSelect` function specified in the attribute. Whenever you change the `selected` flag of a particular `answer` object the `[ngModel]` binding will reflect it over on the UI.

```html
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="answer.selected" (ngModelChange)="onSelect(answer)"/>
```

You can even skip the `answer.selected = !answer.selected` part from your `onSelect` function if you use the two way binding style `[(ngModel)]="answer.selected"`

---

**#Update**

Since `ngModel` directive resides in `FormsModule` you have to import that module into your main `AppModule` imports metadata. You could refer [Angular 2 two way binding using ngModel is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624864/2435473)

Comment: Just tried this but it hasn't changed anything. I also update for two way binding as you suggested.

Comment: @WayneRumble possibly you have forgotten to add [FormsModule](https://angular.io/guide/forms) to the app module

Comment: No, well there is one but its to do with devise authentication, but its kinda supposed to be there

Comment: ive added my app.module.ts but FormsModule is there

Comment: @WayneRumble checked another referenced answer, hope it will help

Comment: @PankajParkar here is a [demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xCI6dwAN6bWjYkWhssck?p=preview) you could add

Comment: I dont see what im missing? sorry

Comment: just figuring out how to use it now

Comment: cant figure out what i need to do for angular 2 on plunkr but its on my giuthub here https://github.com/wrumble/barrelFrontend Sorry