# AngularJS, input textbox not even showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just running some basic default boiler plate code and I edited this file:

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
  <p> {{name}} </p>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
}
```

But this literally does nothing. There is just a blank page. What am I doing wrong? This seems so basic

Answer (score 1):

Since `ngModel` directive included in `FormsModule`, you have to import and add that module inside `imports` metadata option of your `AppModule`.

**Code**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms'; //<-- FormsModule import
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ], //<-- added FormsModule to imports option
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LmsBrT4Af73JDukI4YwN?p=preview)

Comment: @Bana No way, please check plunker.. the `app.module.ts` is the file which you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks bro. It's working. But I'm curios, why was this not provided? I am watching a tutorial and he just did the same basic creation and simply used `[(ngModule)]` right off the bat without needing any of this?

Comment: @Bana I don't to re-write everything here, can you please refer [Angular 2 two way binding using ngModel is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624864/2435473) which has everything mentioned precisely