# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-slide-toggle'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-5

I am trying to get the current value of a `mat-slide-toggle` but unfortunatly I will get an error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-slide-toggle'.
```

I am using the toggle like this in the html part of my component:

```
 <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" [(ngModel)]="showInnerView">
      Default Slide Toggle
 </mat-slide-toggle>
```

Corresponding property in my component:

```
showInnerView: boolean = false;
```

What I am doing wrong?

---

[Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview) of `mat-slide-toggle`

[Official example](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/slide-toggle/slide-toggle-demo.html) of `mat-slide-toggle` together with `[(ngModel)]`

---

Used Versions: Angular: 5.2.4, Angular Material: 5.2.0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ngModel` lives in `FormsModule` of `@angular/forms`, so import that to your `AppModule` (or whichever module you are trying to use it in).

Also see this question: [Angular 2 two way binding using ngModel is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623879/angular-2-two-way-binding-using-ngmodel-is-not-working)

Answer (score 15):

Please try to include FormsModule in your corresponding Module like below

```
@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: I had import @angular/forms included, but only used the ReactiveFormsModule. Including FormsModule helped!

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, after running

```
ng serve
```

it was fixed

Comment: This is not an answer as it does not provide any solution or explanation, please have a look at the tour from StackOverflow on how to answer questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @Ferie, actually it helped me xD I had this error even tho I had FormsModule imported in my component's module. Restarting the application removed this error. Strange, but it works.

Comment: @Symlis I hope you recognise that `ng serve` is just running locally the application: it does not solve the issue by itself. You must have changed something in the app to let the build works.