# Function not being recognised in Angular Project

Tags: angular

I basically have a button that once pressed will output whatever has been typed into the user input.

However my function that assigns the user input to a variable isn't being recognised for some odd reason?

app.component.html:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<h1>Word Hider</h1>
 <p></p>
   <input type="text" class="wordHide" value="Insert Text">
 <p></p>
   <button  id='userIn' (click)='takeUserStr()'>Submit!</button>
<p></p>
   <button>Hide Word!</button>
<div>
  Your Word Is: {{ userWord }}
</div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts:

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


  @NgModule({
     declarations: [
     AppComponent,
   ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule
  ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
export class AppModule {
userWord = 'this is a test';
  ********************function***********************
  takeUserStr(event: any) {
    this.userWord = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
  }

}
```

Comment: You have to put your function in `AppComponent`, not in the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component are isolated in nature, they only understand whats present inside their `context`(this), whatever you kept in the own class. In addition to that it also recognises `Input` + `Output` bindings + `Injectors`

You have kept your function in `AppModule`, which isn't reachable on your component `template`. You should move out that `function` to your `app.component.ts`

Basically everything that is bounded to your component html, that you have to move inside `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  userWord = 'this is a test';

  takeUserStr(event: any) {
     this.userWord = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
  }
}
```

Also pass `$event` object as in parameter of `takeUserStr` function.

```
(click)='takeUserStr($event)'
```

---

Though my recommendation to implement this scenario using `@angular/forms`, either model driven or template driven forms.

Check [Use ngModel with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624864/2435473)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the function declared in app.component.ts , also it should not take any parameter as you defined in **`HTML`**

```
takeUserStr() {
    this.userWord = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
}
```

Comment: Just to add, I'm now getting "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Comment: Did you add it to the app.component.ts? Like @bugs suggested?

Comment: @RukshanDangalla yep!